# Create multiple zipfiles using php

Tags: php, sql, zip

I have a database that has over 2000 image paths. What I would like to do is pull the image paths from the database and zip them up. The only problem I'm having is I need to make multiple zip files with about 200 images in each zip. So the output will be image1.zip, image2.zip and so on. I have tried using easyzip to make a multipart zip but some of my users are having trouble extracting the files. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what easyzip is, but I've had success using PHP's ZipArchive library (I wasn't attempting to zip up as many files as you are, so your results may vary):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Using easyzip though, what errors are your users experiencing?

**UPDATE**

There is a file size limit on .zip files of about 4 gigs.

While it might be unlikely, if these images are photographs or other large size files, you may be coming up against that limit.

**UPDATE (AGAIN)**

I can't comment on easyzip or how you might fix your issue with that, but here is one possible solution in regular PHP if you want to (and have time to) implement it:

```
$files          = $filepaths; // However you have retrieved them from your database
$zipFilepath    = "/path/to/zip/file/";
$baseFilename   = "image";

$filesProcessed = 0;
$x              = 1; //$x will be the .zip filename incrementer
$archive        = "";

foreach ($files as $fileToAdd)
{
    if ($filesProcessed === 0 || !$filesProcessed % 200)
    {
        if ($archive)
        {
            $archive->close();
        }
        $archiveFile  = $zipFilepath . $baseFilename . $x . ".zip";
        $archive      = new ZipArchive();
        $archive->open($archiveFile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        $x++;
    }
    
    $archive->addFile($fileToAdd);
    
    $filesProcessed++;
}
$archive->close();
```

When this concludes, you should have several .zip files in your `$zipFilepath` directory with 200 files inside each.

Comment: When using easyzip the users were getting an error saying invalid zip file when using anything other the winrar. If they use winrar everything works fine, but some of my users are on mac and winrar for mac is command line only and they are having trouble using it.

Comment: I'm not having problems with zipping the images, its zipping 200 of them then starting a new zip file that I'm having a problem with.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I had to change a few thing to get it to work the way I wanted, but its what I was looking for.